# How can I fix the position of Farbtastic ignoring scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, color-picker

I have Farbtastic in a form with many color inputs.

I want the color wheel to stay fixed in the window, son I can scroll through the form maintaining the wheel in the same place.

I tried css position:fixed, but it alters the coordinates system of the picker, so picking colors is impossible.

Any ideas? other color pickers pops from the click, but I do not know if it can be done with Farbtastic because of the coordinates system.

Regards:
Migue

Comment: `position:fixed` works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/gilly3/K8bDE/.  Post a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or adequate code to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You have the solution here : http://code.google.com/p/farbtastic/issues/detail?id=3

Line 163 your must add this with your `#elementId`:

```
pos.x -= + $('#elementId').scrollLeft();
pos.y -= + $('#elementId').scrollTop();
```

Comment: Thank you. Still not working. The picker scrolls, but clicking on it doesn't get the right values.

Answer (score 0):

This problem has a solution. Just upload fixed and minified version (4kB) of the .js file:

http://image2love.com/js/farbtastic2.js

and put your colour picker where you like:

```
#picker {
      z-index: 5; position: fixed; top: 100px; right: 100px;
     }
```

I've been also searching for the solution for some time when I finally came across the solution.